# Pyspark, looping through DataFrame in a more efficient way?

Tags: python, pyspark

can someone maybe tell me a better way to loop through a df in Pyspark in my specific case. I am new to spark, so sorry for the question.

What I am doing is selecting the value of the id column of the df where the song_name is null. I append these to a list and get the track_ids for these values. With these track_ids I make an API-Request to get the missing song_names and replace the null value at that index with the returned song_name.

```
missing_track_name = df.filter(df['track_name'].isNull()).select(df['ID']).collect()

missing_list = [x[0] for x in missing_track_name]

for i in missing_list:

    track_id = df.filter(col('ID')==i).select(df.song_id).collect()

    url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/{0}'.format(track_id)
    request = requests.get(url, headers = header, params = {"limit" : 50})
    data = request.json()

    df = df.withColumn("track_name", when(col("ID") == i, data['name']).otherwise(col("track_name")))
    df = df.withColumn("artist_name", when(col("ID") == i, data['artists'][0]['name']).otherwise(col("artist_name")))
```

Sample rows from my table are (the music is from a friends Spotify, not exactly my taste):

| genre | artist_name | track_name | track_id | popularity | acousticness | danceability | duration_ms | energy | instrumentalness | liveness | loudness | speechiness | tempo | valence | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R&B | Mary J. Blige | Be Without You - Kendu Mix | 2YegxR5As7BeQuVp2U6pek | 65 | 0.083 | 0.724 | 246333 | 0.689 | 0.0 | 0.304 | -5.922 | 0.135 | 146.496 | 0.693 | 0 |
| R&B | Rihanna | Desperado | 6KFaHC9G178beAp7P0Vi5S | 63 | 0.323 | 0.685 | 186467 | 0.61 | 0.0 | 0.102 | -5.221 | 0.0439 | 94.384 | 0.323 | 1 |
| R&B | Yung Bleu | Ice On My Baby (feat. Kevin Gates) - Remix | 6muW8cSjJ3rusKJ0vH5olw | 62 | 0.0675 | 0.762 | 199520 | 0.52 | 3.95e-06 | 0.114 | -5.237 | 0.0959 | 75.047 | 0.0862 | 2 |
| R&B | Surfaces | Heaven Falls / Fall on Me | 7yHqOZfsXYlicyoMt62yC6 | 61 | 0.36 | 0.563 | 240597 | 0.366 | 0.00243 | 0.0955 | -6.896 | 0.121 | 85.352 | 0.768 | 3 |
| R&B | Olivia O'Brien | Love Myself | 4XzgjxGKqULifVf7mnDIQK | 68 | 0.596 | 0.653 | 213947 | 0.621 | 0.0 | 0.0811 | -5.721 | 0.0409 | 100.006 | 0.466 | 4 |

Comment: you can resort to an UDF in this use case. if you can share a few sample rows, we can test and share solutions.

Comment: I have added 5 rows of sample data if that would help :). Thanks a lot so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can resort to an UDF. But I'd suggest you filter the `null` rows and run the UDF only for them.

here's my attempt

```py
def getSpotifyTrackName(trackId, cId, cSecret):
    import requests, base64
    
    # fetch token -- feel free to do this outside the func
    # fetching within this func as token expires within 3600 secs 
    # and might expire midway through big process
    b64_encode_cred = base64.b64encode((cId+':'+cSecret).encode())
    token_url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/'
    token_data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }
    token_header = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b64_encode_cred.decode()
    }

    token_req_json = requests.post(token_url, headers=token_header, data=token_data).json()

    # fetch track details using aforementioned token
    track_url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/{0}'.format(trackId)
    track_header = {
        'Authorization': token_req_json['token_type']+' '+token_req_json['access_token']
    }

    track_data_json = requests.get(track_url,
                                   params = {"limit" : 50}, 
                                   headers=track_header
                                   ).json()
    
    return track_data_json['name'].strip()

# create UDF
getSpotifyTrackName_udf = func.udf(lambda t: getSpotifyTrackName(t, spotify_auth['client_id'], spotify_auth['client_secret']), 
                                   StringType()
                                   )

# use UDF to fetch track names in a new column
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('api_track_name', getSpotifyTrackName_udf('track_id')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----+--------------+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
# |genre|artist_name   |track_name                |track_id              |api_track_name                            |
# +-----+--------------+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
# |R&B  |Mary J. Blige |Be Without You - Kendu Mix|2YegxR5As7BeQuVp2U6pek|Be Without You - Kendu Mix                |
# |R&B  |Rihanna       |null                      |6KFaHC9G178beAp7P0Vi5S|Desperado                                 |
# |R&B  |Yung Bleu     |null                      |6muW8cSjJ3rusKJ0vH5olw|Ice On My Baby (feat. Kevin Gates) - Remix|
# |R&B  |Surfaces      |Heaven Falls / Fall on Me |7yHqOZfsXYlicyoMt62yC6|Heaven Falls / Fall on Me                 |
# |R&B  |Olivia O'Brien|Love Myself               |4XzgjxGKqULifVf7mnDIQK|Love Myself                               |
# +-----+--------------+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I am starting to grasp UDFs now. But lets say I have this null_df and add the new column with the non null values. How could I then get these values from the null_df into the main data frame?

Comment: you replace the null column with the new column, and then you can use `unionByName()` OR join the non-null column to the main data

Comment: Okay, in that case I would have an track_name column and an api_track_name column in the main df . And if the track_name column is null I would have to resort to the api_track_name column?

Comment: yes, after you join the null df with main df, you can use the `coalesce` function on the 2 columns

Comment: Perfect. I now however get the error NoneType object is not subscriptable. The type of the df becomes none type after calling the with function and the udf on it.

Comment: remove the `show` when you're assigning it yo a variable or doing a join. `show` returns nothing, just prints the df.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are thinking about this in kind of a standard programming way, but instead you should be thinking about how to solve this using operations that apply across the entire dataframe. For example, there is no reason to collect list, then iterate over list to make api call, etc. This all happens mostly on the driver and is inefficient.

Instead, I would create a pyspark user defined function (UDF) which makes the API call. This would utilize the workers and employ parallelism and would likely be very fast. Then you simply call this function on your dataframe, like you would any standard pyspark function, and it operates across your entire dataframe. You don't have to loop at all.